# How To make custom title bar for rootview controller in splitterView

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I wanted to customize the title bar of the root view controller in my splitterView for an iPad application. The title bar required to be transparent and with customized font and size.

I tried on my own but could not find any such methods for the same and was unsuccessful with some googled links.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the below link, its helpful

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2079/core-graphics-101-shadows-and-gloss